# Deleted term shown in exposed filter

Tags: 7, views

I'm using exposed [simple hierarchal select](https://www.drupal.org/project/shs) module for a taxonomy in my exposed filter, i have deleted some terms from the taxonomy but the filter  still showing the deleted terms.

I tried clearing caches and cron and even waited one day with no luck!

Any ideas what is the problem??

❤️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disabling the 'JavaScript callback handler' module solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be revisions or taxonomy revisions issue 
module documentation  says 
This module enables revisions for the taxonomy terms.

The users will have an option to create new revision for a taxonomy term as for
nodes. This means when a taxonomy term is edited in the default form, a new
checkbox is displayed for revision creation. If clicked a textarea will appear
to fill a revision log message.

Also on the taxonomy term edit page a new menu tab appears after the module
installation which will list all of the taxonomy term's revisions and provides

Comment: I don't have taxonomy revisions module installed. And when i deleted the term it disappeared from the taxonomy menu but still in the exposed filter.